# Minecraft Worlds Crash

Tags: minecraft-forge

**Please Help My Minecraft Crashes When I join A World. BTW I am using mods. Here Is My Crash Report**

---

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

> WARNING: coremods are present:   Java8CheckerCoremod
>   (Pixelmon-1.8-4.1.1-universal.jar) Contact their authors BEFORE
>   contacting forge
>
> // Ooh. Shiny.
>
> Time: 1/17/16 11:44 AM Description: Exception in server tick loop
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception in server tick loop     at
>   com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.worldGeneration.structure.towns.ComponentTownPart.func_74875_a(ComponentTownPart.java:55)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.StructureStart.func_75068_a(StructureStart.java:45)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.world.gen.structure.MapGenStructure.func_175794_a(MapGenStructure.java:93)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderGenerate.func_73153_a(ChunkProviderGenerate.java:415)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.func_73153_a(ChunkProviderServer.java:269)
>     at net.minecraft.world.chunk.Chunk.func_76624_a(Chunk.java:1126)    at
>   net.minecraftforge.common.chunkio.ChunkIOProvider.callStage2(ChunkIOProvider.java:52)
>     at
>   net.minecraftforge.common.chunkio.ChunkIOProvider.callStage2(ChunkIOProvider.java:12)
>     at
>   net.minecraftforge.common.util.AsynchronousExecutor.skipQueue(AsynchronousExecutor.java:344)
>     at
>   net.minecraftforge.common.util.AsynchronousExecutor.getSkipQueue(AsynchronousExecutor.java:302)
>     at
>   net.minecraftforge.common.chunkio.ChunkIOExecutor.syncChunkLoad(ChunkIOExecutor.java:12)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.loadChunk(ChunkProviderServer.java:117)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.func_73158_c(ChunkProviderServer.java:92)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71222_d(MinecraftServer.java:302)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71247_a(IntegratedServer.java:112)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.func_71197_b(IntegratedServer.java:126)
>     at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:438)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known
>
> ### details is as follows:
>
> -- System Details -- Details:     Minecraft Version: 1.8  Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0   Java Version: 1.8.0_25,
>   Oracle Corporation    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation  Memory: 876196800 bytes (835 MB) /
>   2034081792 bytes (1939 MB) up to 2134114304 bytes (2035 MB)   JVM
>   Flags: 6 total;
>   -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
>   -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M    IntCache: cache: 11, tcache: 0, allocated: 13, tallocated: 95   FML: MCP v9.10 FML v8.0.99.99 Minecraft
>   Forge 11.14.4.1577 7 mods loaded, 7 mods active   States: 'U' =
>   Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' =
>   Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E'
>   = Errored     UCHIJAA mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar)    UCHIJAA FML{8.0.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader]
>   (forge-1.8-11.14.4.1577.jar)      UCHIJAA Forge{11.14.4.1577} [Minecraft
>   Forge] (forge-1.8-11.14.4.1577.jar)   UCHIJAA customnpcs{1.8.0}
>   [CustomNPCs] (CustomNPCs_1.8.0.jar)   UCHIJAA cfm{3.5.1}
>   [§9MrCrayfish's Furniture Mod] (MrCrayfishFurnitureModv3.5.1(1.8).jar)
>     UCHIJAA pixelmon{4.1.1} [Pixelmon] (Pixelmon-1.8-4.1.1-universal.jar)
>     UCHIJAA worldedit{6.1} [WorldEdit] (worldedit-forge-mc1.8-6.1.jar) 
>     Loaded coremods (and transformers):  Java8CheckerCoremod
>   (Pixelmon-1.8-4.1.1-universal.jar)
>         GL info: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.     Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)   Player Count:
>   0 / 8; []     Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)    Is Modded:
>   Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions... Doesn't seem like you are making mods, and you've supplied no code.  This is off-topic.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a generic tech support site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete all the mods and start again as you have installed some that have overlapped.